# Microsoft Ad Control - Black box when launching app

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

I am implementing Ad Control into a WP7 app. When I launch the application, a black ad box appears for a second or two then disappears or it changes showing the ad.

I do not want the black box to be shown.

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using for this?